# Testing controller with fake session

Tags: java, testing, playframework-2.1

**I want to write test for my controller:**

```
Result changeAction = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Users.changePassword());
assertThat(status(changeAction)).isEqualTo(OK);
```

I have a http status code - 300.

That's right it is redirect because I have a class named Secured

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.*;

public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator {

    @Override
    public String getUsername(Context ctx) {
        return ctx.session().get("userId");
    }

    @Override
    public Result onUnauthorized(Context ctx) {
        return redirect(routes.Users.login(ctx.request().uri()));
    }


}
```

And when I use the `@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)` annotation for controller method it redirects if session with "userId" do not exists.

*So the question is, how can I fake the session?*

I tried obviously call `Controller.session("usderId", "2");`

And got an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.

    at play.mvc.Http$Context.current(Http.java:30)
    at play.mvc.Controller.session(Controller.java:54)
    at play.mvc.Controller.session(Controller.java:61)
    at controllers.UsersTest.testUnloginedChangePassword(UsersTest.java:35)
```

***My question is: How to fake the session for controller?***

And one additional question: how to test routes without using deprecated API, like `Result result = routeAndCall(fakeRequest(GET, "/change_password"));` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `withSession(String, String)` method of `fakeRequest` to put things in the Session. Note that this returns a `fakeRequest` so you can chain that method if you need to put multiple keys in the session.

Your test could then look something like this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
   running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           String username = "Aerus";
           Result res = route(fakeRequest("GET", "/")
                            .withSession("username", username)
                            .withSession("key","value"));
           assert(contentAsString(res).contains(username));
       }
   });
}
```

Note also that I used the `route` method and not `routeAndCall`, the first is the replacement of the deprecated method.

Comment: I find the solution 3 minutes ago, before look at your answer. Anyway thank you, again! :D