# Simulate session using WithServer

Tags: session, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to port tests from using FakeRequest to using WithServer.

In order to simulate a session with FakeRequest, it is possible to use `WithSession("key", "value")` as suggested in this post: [Testing controller with fake session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007522/testing-controller-with-fake-session/17009034#17009034)

However when using WithServer, the test now looks like:

```
"render the users page" in WithServer {
  val users = await(WS.url("http://localhost:" + port + "/users").get)

  users.status must equalTo(OK)
  users.body   must contain("Users")
}
```

Since there is no `WithSession(..)` method available, I tried instead `WithHeaders(..)` (does that even make sense?), to no avail.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this question, which is relatively old:

[Add values to Session during testing (FakeRequest, FakeApplication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753654/add-values-to-session-during-testing-fakerequest-fakeapplication)

The first answer to that question seems to have been a pull request to add `.WithSession(...)` to FakeRequest, but it was not applicable to `WS.url`

The second answer seems to give me what I need:

Create cookie:

```
val sessionCookie = Session.encodeAsCookie(Session(Map("key" -> "value")))
```

Create and execute request:

```
val users = await(WS.url("http://localhost:" + port + "/users")
        .withHeaders(play.api.http.HeaderNames.COOKIE -> Cookies.encodeCookieHeader(Seq(sessionCookie))).get())

users.status must equalTo(OK)
users.body   must contain("Users")
```

Finally, the assertions will pass properly, instead of redirecting me to the login page

Note: I am using Play 2.4, so I use Cookies.encodeCookieHeader, because Cookies.encode is deprecated